# Classical Newton method for minimization

Tags: optimization

For a quadratic convex function Classical Newton method for unconstrained optimization reaches the minimum point in one iteration. It this true?
If so, what is the proof ?

Comment: The minimum of a quadratic convex function, even in multiple variables, amounts to the root of a linear system, which the Newton iteration finds (using the inverse Jacobian in the multivariable case).

Comment: In how many iteration does it find ?

Comment: In one iteration.

Comment: Can you suggest the proof of getting it in one iteration for multivariate case

Answer (score 1):

Recall that a quadratic convex function, $f(\overline{u}) = \overline{u}A\overline{u}^T + \overline{u}b^T$, has a unique global minimum characterized by the vanishing of first partial derivatives.

Thus if $\nabla_f$ is the gradient of $f$, the minimizing point $\overline{u}$ is also the solution of the system $\nabla_f = 0$.  Minimizing $f(\overline{u})$ by Newton's method means to solve the system $\nabla_f = 0$ by Newton iterations.

However one such iteration suffices because the gradient of $f$ is a linear function of $\overline{u}$, and the Newton iteration step is simply to solve the corresponding system.

Comment: I got the idea clearly. Can you suggest me some good material about this to read ?

Comment: The Hessian of $f$ is the matrix of second partial derivatives, and when we apply Newton's method to solve $\nabla_f = 0$, the "correction" to our initial value $\overline{u}$ is computed using the Hessian inverse.  For some background see [these class notes](http://www.math.udel.edu/~angell/Opt/conv_fcn.pdf) by Prof. Tom Angell at Univ. of Delaware, but your case is the simple one where the Hessian is a constant matrix (the same for every $\overline{u}$).